# RetrieveMultiple does not return all attributes

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I'm running the following code against a fairly standard CRM 4.0 installation.

```
            List<ConditionExpression> cons = new List<ConditionExpression>();

            QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression();
            query.EntityName = "systemuser";

            cons.Add(new ConditionExpression());
            cons[cons.Count - 1].AttributeName = "isdisabled";
            cons[cons.Count - 1].Operator = ConditionOperator.Equal;
            cons[cons.Count - 1].Values = new object[] { false };

            FilterExpression filter = new FilterExpression();

            // Set the properties of the filter.
            filter.FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.And;
            filter.Conditions.AddRange(cons.ToArray());

            //query.ColumnSet = new AllColumns();
            query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(new string[]{"systemuserid","fullname","firstname","lastname"});
            query.Criteria = filter;
            query.Orders.Add(new OrderExpression("fullname", OrderType.Ascending));

            RetrieveMultipleRequest RMR = new RetrieveMultipleRequest();
            RMR.Query = query;
            RMR.ReturnDynamicEntities = true;

            RetrieveMultipleResponse resp = (RetrieveMultipleResponse)CRM.Execute(RMR);
```

For some reason the list of dynamic entities which is returned only contains the systemuserid attribute.  If I use an AllColumns() I get a selection of columns (by no means all) which still does not include the fullname, firstname and lastname columns.

The records in question definitly have values for the requested fields.

Any thoughts...?

Comment: Do your records have values for the requested fields?

Answer (score 2):

Resolved - one system user had blank values for firstname, lastname and fullname - filling these in made the query start retrieving these values for all the other users as well.